# move_and_slide moves all instances of KinematicBody2D

Tags: python, godot

Hi I'm using Python Godot and I'm having an issue with having multiple rigid bodies in a scene.

To move all my instances of RigidBody2D I use the move_and_slide method. When I run the project, all velocities that are applied in 2 different scripts are applied to all RigidBody2Ds.

So the Player moves in a random direction as well as up and down and the ball is moving up and down and in a random direction.

The desired outcome would be that the player moves up and down based on my input and the ball moves in a random direction.

I've made a 1 min video displaying my issue since I'ts a bit hard to describe: https://youtu.be/SAR6KFySayM

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Someone on the projects GitHub was able to help me out.
It turn out that there is a bug where Vector2.Zero is somekind of global variable.
So I had to change Vector2.Zero to Vector2(0,0).
That fixed it!